# Как обновить данные в sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Я меняю данные в sqlite, но при смене версии бд на 2,3,4 и т.д. изменения не происходят в приложении. Чтобы новые строки появились, мне нужно заново ставить приложение на устройство. Метод onUpgrade() вызывается, но что там писать, я не знаю, так как я новичок в этом деле. В интернете не могу найти ответа. 
Буду очень благодарен, если поможете.

**DBHelper.java**

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper{

private static final String DB_NAME ="database.db"; 

private static final int DB_VER = 4;

private static DBHelper instance; 


public static synchronized DBHelper

getInstance(Context context) {

DBHelper dBHelper; 

synchronized (DBHelper.class) { 

if (instance == null) { 

instance = new DBHelper(context); 

} 

dBHelper = instance;

}

return dBHelper;

}

public DBHelper(Context context) {

super(context, DB_NAME, null, 4);

}  

public List<Category> getAllCategories() { 

 SQLiteDatabase db = instance.getWritableDatabase();

     Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Category", null); 

  List<Category> categories = new ArrayList(); 


  if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

 while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) { 

              categories.add(new Category(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")), Double.valueOf(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("Coordin1"))), Double.valueOf(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("Coordin2"))),

cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("timework")), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("brand")), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Adresa")), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Image")), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PC"))));           

cursor.moveToNext();   

}   

}

 cursor.close();  

db.close();      

return categories;  }   

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

 } 

}
```

Comment: Изменения вы должны сделать сами в методе `onUpgrade`

Comment: @woesss то есть мне нужно заново вызвать cursor и пройтись по бд?

Comment: Давайте сначала разберёмся что имеется в виду под словами _Я меняю данные в sqlite_ ? Как и где вы это делаете? Где и как создаётся сама база, откуда берутся данные?

Comment: @woesss я добавляю строки в программе на Винде,DB browser for sqlite, иногда обновляю данные в уже существующих строках в определенных столбцах. База создана там же. Из этой базы берутся данные по столбцам.

Comment: Если вы изменяете только содержимое ячеек, добавляете/удаляете строки, то апгрейд тут не при чём. Реализовывать апгрейд и повышать версию нужно когда меняются структуры таблиц (имена, количество, порядок колонок), удаляются, добавляются таблицы. Тут вопрос в другом - как бд с винды у вас попадает на Андроид-устройство?

Comment: @woesss она находится в папке asset в приложении. Через программу я ее нахожу в этой папке и редактирую

Comment: @woesss то есть при смене названия колонки с "а" на "в", я вызываю метод onUpgrade и если, допустим создаю новую колонку, правильно? А если я добавляю строку или меняю данные в строке, то что мне нужно делать, чтобы в приложении эти изменения были видны? Не методом update?

Comment: Вы [android-sqlite-asset-helper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) используете? Такие вещи надо сразу указывать. Там другой механизм обновления, посмотрите их семпл [тык](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper/tree/master/samples/database-v13-upgrade) и описание [тык](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper#database-upgrades)

Comment: @woesss спасибо за ссылку! Метод, который там был указан помог мне) Всего вам наилучшего)

Answer (score 2):

Версия бд меняется только если меняется ее схема. Добавилась новая таблица или новый столбец в таблице. С новые индексами может быть удобно менять версию бд, но это индивидуальный вопрос. Если меняются данные(строки) - номер версии не меняется

Если все таки именно схема изменилась, то у вас 2 варианта действий - удалить все старые данные и создать новую бд, или преобразовать старые данные под новую схему. И то, и другое делается в onUpgrade.

SQLiteAssetHelper реализует обычный SQLiteOpenHelper. В когда вы просите экземпляр бд он копирует файл из asset на диск и открывает бд уже с диска. То есть чтобы на устройстве, где была уже создана бд со старой схемой, вам нужно в onUpgrade просто удалить файл бд, и когда в другом месте вы попросите открыть бд - она заново скопируется из ассетов и будет свежей версии.

как-то так:

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if(oldVersion != newVersion){
        File db_path = context.getDatabasePath();
        if(db_path.exist){
            db_path.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Мне помог только метод  setForcedUpgrade();